# What is a word for someone who is extremley picky and unthankful for what he has?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

Can someone give me a word that describes a person who wants to have everything at a very high level and doesn't want it if it's anything below that? For instance such a person might not want to eat a Philly Cheesesteak unless it's actually from Philadelphia, or might refuse to play a game that is at 15–30 frames and insist that it has to be at 60 to be playable.

Someone who is extremely picky and isn't thankful enough for small things.

Comment: 'Over-privileged'? Please supply an example sentence with a blank where the word you want would belong.

Comment: **Perfectionist** would address the examples you gave, but not the lack of gratitude. **Ingrate** would address the lack of thankfulness, but not the perfectionism. I don't know of a single word that would convey both of those qualities simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Finicky, ingrate, persnickety, hard to please, malcontent, fussbudget, snooty... There are myriad words for this.  They are manyfold and sundry.  Whichever you should use would hinge on whatever nuance you wish to capture.

Answer (score 1):

A **snob**, or better yet - a [hyphenated] snob:

I won't eat at Red Lobster - I'm a *seafood-snob*.

Don't tell him you bought that tie for $10 - he's a *clothes-snob*.

Comment: Snob was the first thing that came to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Uncontented or Dissatisfied for the bests.

Answer (score 0):

I would describe your hypothetical person as a [**pretentious**](https://www.google.co.kr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=pretentious) [**hypercritical**](https://www.google.co.kr/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=hypercritical) person who thinks he/she is [**too cool for school**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=too+cool+for+school).

**Pretentious**

> adjective
>
> attempting to impress by affecting greater importance, talent, culture, etc., than is actually possessed.

**Hypercritical**

> adjective
>
> excessively and unreasonably critical, especially of small faults.

**Too cool for school**

> idiom
>
> A state in which a person thinks him or herself superior to everyone else in a given group or in general. Generally used sarcastically